# When using monger, do I need to supply connection each request?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

[In the documentation](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/inserting.html), the mongodb connection is established once, before being used without passing the connection to each command, is that the proper way to use monger, or should I pass the database connection to each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with single database then it's best to set the connection once:

```
(mg/connect! db-spec)
```

But it's not a good idea when you have multiple databases. Monger have `with-connection` macro ([see API docs](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/inserting.html#working_with_multiple_databases)) for this case:

```
(mg/with-connection db-connection
  ...)
```

You may establish all connections once during the initialization of your app:

```
(def conn1 (mg/connect db-spec))
```

and then use them:

```
(mg/with-connection conn1
  ...)
```

**Update.** In our application we have a hash-map of all database connections:

```
(def  ^:dynamic
      ^clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
      *connections*
      {})

(defn connect! [db]
  {:pre [(contains? mongo-config db)]}
  (if (-> db *connections* nil?)
      (let [conn (mg/connect (get mongo-config db))]
        (alter-var-root #'*connections*
                        assoc
                        db
                        { :conn conn
                          :db   (mg/get-db conn (name db))})))
  (-> *connections* db :conn))

(defmacro with-db [db & body]
  "Eval body using :amonplus or :statistic db"
  `(mg/with-connection (connect! ~db)
    (mg/with-db        (clojure.core/-> *connections* ~db :db)
      ~@body)))
```

`mongo-config` variable stores specification for all our databases and `with-db` macro makes it easy to access them by their names:

```
(with-db :my-db
  ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now (version 2.0) is necessary for all key public API functions use an explicit DB/connection/GridFS object.

so:

```
(require '[monger.collection :as mc])

(mc/insert db "libraries" {:name "Monger"})
```

To get this work:

```
 (let [conn (mg/connect)
     db   (mg/get-db conn "monger-test")]
      (mc/insert db "libraries" {:name "Monger"}))
```

How I can use the "db" reference accross all my code.